# import and export unexpected token export tho already install babel

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have some error like this when I want to import and export and run it on nodejs

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export default function try(test){
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

my package.json is like this

```
{
  "name": "importExport",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

and my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "es2015"]
}
```

I have tried follow tutorial on internet too using babel and many method I tried , but it still doest working for import and export to run my `node index.js`

can anyone help me to fix this and what should I set and install again ??

I tried the node --experimental-modules also, with file `.mjs` and when I tried import and export still doest working